# Java generics - incompatible bounds

Tags: java, generics

I have this line of code:

```
messageProcessorFactory.getMessageProcessor(s.getEntry()).process(mapper.readValue(message, s.getEntry()));
```

With these definitions:

```
public<T extends BaseTopicEntry> AbstractMessageProcessor<T> getMessageProcessor(Class<T> entry)
```

...

```
private final Class<? extends BaseTopicEntry> entry;
```

...

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageProcessor<T extends BaseTopicEntry> {

    public abstract void process(T message);

}
```

And mapper is Jackson's mapper.

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

I get this error - why?

> Error:(34, 95) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: capture#1 of ? extends ro.billing.grecotopicconsumer.entity.BaseTopicEntry
>       upper bounds: capture#2 of ? extends ro.billing.grecotopicconsumer.entity.BaseTopicEntry,java.lang.Object

Comment: The error message basically says "_You have 2 generic types both extend from BaseTopicEntry but the actual types are not necessarily the same_"

Comment: can you give a bit more detail, it seems to me like you are passing`ro.billing.grecotopicconsumer.entity.BaseTopicEntry` but the bound is `ro.billing.grecotopicconsumer.entity.BaseTopicEntry,java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @dpr I thought about the same thing, but if I'm not missing something, following the flow of commands, getMessageProcessor will be parameterized the same as what Jackson's mapper will return, as they both base on s.getEntry().. but this is me thinking as a human, maybe I'm missing something or the compiler doesn't make these connections?

Comment: @Humming bird: I see the second bound, maybe I don't understand it - isn't every type bound to Object? How can I have BaseTopicEntry  as a bound without also having Object as a bound?

Comment: By the way, if I parameterize everywhere with 'T' instead of 'T extends BaseTopicEntry' everything works, but I wanted to be more type safe.

Comment: I can't believe it. If I change to 'public abstract class AbstractMessageProcessor<T extends BaseTopicEntry, Object> {' everything works. Why? :)

Comment: Welcome to the world of Java generics. I have no idea, but I'm curious on the answer...